# Synchronized methods to avoid deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, synchronized, locks

I have two synchronized methods and I'm using the mediator design pattern. 
I'm trying to avoid deadlocks, which is (from what I understand) for example when a thread has a lock on a variable res1 but needs a lock on variable res2. The other thread needs the lock for res1 but has the lock for res2 - resulting in a deadlock, right?

Assuming my understanding of deadlocks are correct, then my question is whether or not I have solved the issue of deadlock in this code?

I have two synchronized methods and two threads.

```
public class Producer extends Thread {
    private Mediator med;
    private int id;
    private static int count = 1;

    public Producer(Mediator m) {
        med = m;
        id = count++;
    }

    public void run() {
        int num;
        while(true) {
            num = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            med.storeMessage(num);
            System.out.println("P-" + id + ": " + num);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {
    private Mediator med;
    private int id;
    private static int count = 1;

    // laver kopling over til mediator
    public Consumer(Mediator m) {
        med = m;
        id = count++;
    }

    public void run() {
        int num;
        while(true) {
            num = med.retrieveMessage();
            System.out.println("C" + id + ": " + num);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Mediator {
    private int number;
    private boolean slotFull = false;

    public synchronized void storeMessage(int num) {
        while(slotFull == true) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }  
        slotFull = true;
        number = num;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized int retrieveMessage() {
        while(slotFull == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        slotFull = false;
        notifyAll();
        return number;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MediatorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mediator mb = new Mediator(); 
        new Producer(mb).start();
        new Producer(mb).start();
        new Producer(mb).start();

        new Consumer(mb).start();
        new Consumer(mb).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> for example when a thread has a lock on a variable res1 but needs a lock on variable res2

What matters is not that there are two *variables*, what matters is that there must be two (or more) *locks*.

The names "res1" and "res2" are meant to suggest two *resources* each of which may have one or more variables, and each of which has its own lock.  Here's where you get into trouble:

```
final Object lock1 = new Object();
final Object lock2 = new Object();

public void method1() {
    synchronized (lock1) {
        // Call Thread.sleep(1000) here to simulate the thread losing its time slice.
        synchronized(lock2) {
            doSomethingThatRequiresBothLocks
        }
    }
}

public void method2() {
    synchronized (lock2) {
        // Do the same here 'cause you can't know which thread will get to run first.
        synchronized(lock1) {
            doSomethingElseThatRequiresBothLocks()
        }
    }
}
```

If thread A calls `method1()`, there is a very small chance that it could lose its *time slice* (i.e., turn to run) just after it successfully locks `lock1`, but before it locks `lock2`.

Then, while thread A is waiting its turn to run again, thread B calls `method2()`.  Thread B will be able to lock `lock2`, but then it gets stuck because `lock1` is locked by thread A.  Furthermore, when thread A gets to run again, it will immediately be blocked when it tries to lock `lock2` which is owned by thread B.  Neither thread will ever be able to continue from that point.

---

In real code, it's never so obvious.  When it happens in real-life, it usually is because of some unforseen interaction between code from two or more different modules that may not even be aware of each other, but which access the same common resources.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the basic deadlock problem is correct. With your second question about validity of your solution to the deadlock problem, you've only got 1 lock, so I'd say "yes" by default, since the deadlock you described isn't possible in this situation

Comment: Thank you :)

I got an exam in a few days and I'm planning on describing how to solve deadlocks. It requires good design, but I thought it would look something like the above mentioned code.

Do you know how to solve deadlocks? I'm thinking maybe a theoretical explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @ControlAltDel has said. And your understanding of a deadlock matches mine. Whereas there are a few different ways in which a deadlock can manifest itself, the way you describe -- inconsistently acquiring multiple monitors by involved threads (methods) causes deadlock.

Another way would be to (for example,) sleep while holding a lock. As you coded correctly, when the producer finds that `slotFull = true`, it waits, **giving up the lock**, so the other thread (consumer, which is sharing the same instance of `Mediator` with producer) can make progress potentially causing this thread also to make progress after it gets a notification. If you had chosen to call `Thread.sleep()` instead (naively hoping that someone will cause the sleep to end when the condition would be false), then it would cause a deadlock because this thread is sleeping, still holding the lock, denying access to the other thread.

Answer (score -1):

Every object has one lock which restrict multiple threads to access same block of code or method when you use synchronized keyword.

Coming to your problem, it will not deadlock.

If you have two independent attribute in a class shared by multiple threads, you must synchronized the access to each variable, but there is no problem if one thread is accessing one of the attribute and another thread accessing the other at the same time.

```
class Cinema {
private long vacanciesCinema1;  private long vacanciesCinema2;
private final Object controlCinema1, controlCinema2;
public Cinema() {
    controlCinema1 = new Object();
    controlCinema2 = new Object();
    vacanciesCinema1 = 20;
    vacanciesCinema2 = 20;
}
public boolean sellTickets1(int number) {
    synchronized (controlCinema1) {
        if (number < vacanciesCinema1) {
            vacanciesCinema1 -= number;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
public boolean sellTickets2(int number) {
    synchronized (controlCinema2) {
        if (number < vacanciesCinema2) {
            vacanciesCinema2 -= number;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
public boolean returnTickets1(int number) {
    synchronized (controlCinema1) {
        vacanciesCinema1 += number;
        return true;
    }
}
public boolean returnTickets2(int number) {
    synchronized (controlCinema2) {
        vacanciesCinema2 += number;
        return true;
    }
}
public long getVacanciesCinema1() {
    return vacanciesCinema1;
}

public long getVacanciesCinema2() {
    return vacanciesCinema2;
}
```

}

```
class TicketOffice1 implements Runnable {
private final Cinema cinema;

public TicketOffice1(Cinema cinema) {
    this.cinema = cinema;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    cinema.sellTickets1(3);
    cinema.sellTickets1(2);
    cinema.sellTickets2(2);
    cinema.returnTickets1(3);
    cinema.sellTickets1(5);
    cinema.sellTickets2(2);
    cinema.sellTickets2(2);
    cinema.sellTickets2(2);
}
```

}

```
public class CinemaMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cinema cinema = new Cinema();
    TicketOffice1 ticketOffice1 = new TicketOffice1(cinema);
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(ticketOffice1, "TicketOffice1");
    TicketOffice2 ticketOffice2 = new TicketOffice2(cinema);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(ticketOffice2, "TicketOffice2");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    try {
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.printf("Room 1 Vacancies: %d\n", cinema.getVacanciesCinema1());
    System.out.printf("Room 2 Vacancies: %d\n", cinema.getVacanciesCinema2());
}
```

}

Comment: Synchronize does not prevent deadlock.  On the contrary, synchronizing without taking proper precautions can introduce the potential for deadlock.

Comment: Yes, synchronize key word should be used with precaution.